# wp schedule event is calling each time on page load

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, cron

I am new to wordpress and I am trying to create a cron job for wordpress plugin that will call hourly to publish the posts.

I am scheduling the event on button click(I dont want to schedule it on activation.).
it is scheduling successfully on button click (I can check it using wp_get_schedule())

Following is my code

```
if (isset($_POST['synch_categories'])) {
            wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_hourly_event');
            if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_hourly_event' ) ) {
                wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'sixty_seconds', 'my_hourly_event');
            }
             $schedule = wp_get_schedule( 'my_hourly_event' );
             print_r($schedule);
    }
```

In the constructor I am doing this

```
    add_filter( 'cron_schedules', array($this,'add_new_intervals'));
    add_action('my_hourly_event', array($this,'do_this_hourly'));
```

This is my custom interval function

```
   function add_new_intervals( $schedules ) {
        $schedules['sixty_seconds'] = array(
            'interval' => 60,
            'display'  => esc_html__( 'Every 60 Seconds' ),
        );

        return $schedules;
    }
```

This is the function

```
public function do_this_hourly() {
 //all the functionality
}
```

My cronjob link is http://96.125.170.159/~autoblog/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1

I have add This lin in the wp-config.php
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);

I am following these links
https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/schedule-functions-in-your-plugins-with-wordpress-cron/

But the problem is that the function do_this_hourly() is calling each time when I refresh the page and if I implement the condition

```
if($_GET['doing_wp_cron']=='1'){
        add_filter( 'cron_schedules', array($this,'add_new_intervals'));
        add_action('my_hourly_event', array($this,'do_this_hourly'));
}
```

The function do_this_hourly() does not call at all.

I am trying to make it work from last 2 days.Please help me.

Thanks.